# How to update playwright browsers in nextjs vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel, playwright

I added a new feature on my app which includes the usages of `playwright-aws-lambda` in a page's static props.

When I deploy my app, I am receiving the following error saying:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/url/of/some/page". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
at Object.launchChromium (/vercel/path0/node_modules/playwright-aws-lambda/dist/src/chromium.js:97:47)
    at async generateOgImage (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/blog/[...slug].js:21:21)
    at async getStaticProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/blog/[...slug].js:122:25)
    at async renderToHTML (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:470:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:253:36
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
```

there is also an other message which is not part of an error or warning that says:

```
browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /vercel/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1019/chrome-linux/chrome
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     npx playwright install                                              ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I tried running the specified command on my machine but it doesn't do anything on the repo I am deploying. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I encounter the same problem with SvelteKit and playwright on vercel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this by running the command shown in the logs in my build script:

```json
// package.json

{
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "build": "next build && npx playwright install",
  },
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error browserType.launch: Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1067/chrome-linux/chrome

Answer (score 0):

playwright is to heavy for that, if I remember correctly there is a 15MB limitation.
In your package.json the dependencies should look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^6",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "playwright-core": "^1.27.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "playwright": "^1.27.1"
  }
```

that way when in productions (running on aws servers) it uses the light version.

However when trying that I got a 504-timeout since I'm using a free account that is limited to 5 Sec. I found Puppeteer to be much quicker and better for the job.

Comment: Puppeteer is too large (50mb+) this is why many are using playwright instead